# Have the name of a Variable inside another in dart

Tags: php, flutter, variables, dart, dynamic

Hi i want to know if theres a way to get a value from variable inside another one in dart language like this:

Var a = “data”;
Var b = “a”;

I have the name of variable i need inside another.
How Can we do this on dart?
Like using $$variable in php or innerHTML in JavaScript.

I don’t  know the name of variable just know that the name is on another variable.
Thanks

In php i do this:

$var1=“Aaa”;
$var2=“var1”;

Echo($$var2);

This shows “aaa”. I want to do this on dart

Comment: What you are looking for is 'reflection', the ability for code to look into at itself dynamically. However, I don't believe that you can do this easily - and whatever you wish to do with this functionality, there are likely significantly better ways of doing it if you take the time to learn the ins and outs of the language.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
final first = 'first variable';
final second = 'second variable with $first';
```

Comment: No. In second variable i have the name of the variable that have the data i want. I want to access the data using the second variable

Comment: Can you update your question and add more examples?

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This is not a valid solution to the asker's problem - the author wants to refer to a variable by its name as a string, a la reflection.